# Finding all phone numbers

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, substring

So I have this `file.txt` that contains a source code of a web page. I'm trying to get all the phone numbers from `file.txt` into another file one in each line. All the phone numbers in source code are stuck between a string `tel:` and `;`

So far I have successfully saved source code of a web page into file.txt with:

```
echo $(wget http://www.some-web-page.com -q -O ) > file.txt
```

For just printing out all the phone numbers I used:

```
sed -e 's/tel:\(.*\);/' file.txt
```

but I get the whole file.txt?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use grep instead of `sed` . The reason why i choose `grep` means, grep is a tool which prints each match in a separate line.

```
grep -oP 'tel:\K.*?(?=;)' file.txt
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
tel:                     'tel:'
\K                       '\K' (resets the starting point of the
                         reported match)
.*?                      matches any character except \n (0 or more times) non-greedily
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  ;                        ';'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

**Update:**

```
$ cat file
tel:02134343, 3646848393; tel:02134343;
tel:02134344;
$ grep -oP '(?:tel:|(?<!^)\G)\K\d*(?=[^;\n]*;)' file
02134343
3646848393
02134343
02134344
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! Is there any way to upgrade this for examples like: 
tel:02134343, 3646848393; 
so that I can have 02134343  in one line and 3646848393 in next?

Comment: how can I modify grep -oP 'tel:\K.*?(?=;)' file.txt so that it looks for phone numbers between strings tel: and bbr?

Comment: just remove the `;` from `(?=)` and replace it with `bbr` like `grep -oP 'tel:\K.*?(?=bbr)'`

Comment: sorry my mistake I meant how to replace ; with some string that has space in it because it doesn't work with this grep -oP 'tel:\K.*?(?= bbr)'

Comment: Heaping additional requirements after you receive a good answer is not good form. Perhaps at this point you should accept one of these answers and post a new question with clear and exhaustive input and output examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for showing phone numbers in specially formatted case

```
grep -Po 'tel:\d{3}[\s\-_]?\d{3}[\s\-_]?\d{4}' file.txt|cut -f2 -d':'
```

It will extract formatted numbers such as follows

```
***-*******
**********
*** *******
***-***-****
```